Why did Lenny put five bullets in his car seat at the end of Memento?
In Memento, why did Lenny put five bullets in his car seat at the end of the movie?
After killing Jimmy, he took his clothes and his car and put five bullets in his actual car; the next time he arrives, he picks up the bullet. Has he had some realizations in his head before killing Teddy? I'm so confused about Lenny's intention.

It's not exactly obvious what his intention was in that moment, so everything out there is pretty much speculation. For example, this was one of the questions asked recently on this Reddit thread. However, here are my thoughts based on what we can infer from the film.
When Leonard puts the bullets on the seat, his voiceover narration says:

I'm not a killer… I'm just someone who wanted to make things right.

Interestingly, in this script the line was apparently originally:

I'm not a killer… but right now I need to be.

Leonard is mad at Teddy and he doesn't accept Teddy's claim that he's a killer. He could take the gun and shoot Teddy immediately, but he doesn't. If he thought Teddy killed his wife, he probably would do just that. But he eliminates this possibility by ditching the bullets (and the truck they are in). But Leonard also keeps the unloaded gun which belonged to Teddy, possibly to serve as a link to the bullets he abandoned. Plus he doesn't trust Teddy so he doesn't have much reason to give Teddy back his gun, loaded or not. Teddy thinks the gun is loaded; he doesn't know there are bullets in the truck. Teddy is probably a bit scared of Leonard as he should be, but it's not that gun that he should be worried about in this moment.
If Leonard wanted to avoid direct responsibility but still be sure that when his mind resets he would kill Teddy he could have immediately written "He is the one. Kill him" on the photo. Instead he leaves more subtle hints for himself by writing "Don't believe his lies" and noting Teddy's license plate as a clue related to his John G.
Leonard eventually does come to the conclusion that he has to kill Teddy as a result of the wheels set in motion at the chronological beginning of the story. Leonard sets Teddy up to eventually be killed at some point by him, but in that moment he doesn't make it an absolute certainty. He puts himself on Teddy's trail, making Teddy his new "John G":

You think I just want another puzzle to solve? Another John G. to look for? You're a John G. So you can be my John G. Do I lie to myself to be happy? In your case Teddy, yes I will.

Again, the script here is a bit different:

Maybe I’m not finished yet. Maybe I need to be sure that you won’t ever use me again.
You’re a John G.? Fine, then you can be my John G.

Leonard destroys evidence that would contradict this new path, like the photo of Jimmy. He probably knows he might eventually end up back at this building and he will see the truck and the bullets and it will trigger his suspicions. Or maybe his primary goal was just to get rid of the bullets, and he didn't want Teddy to know the gun wasn't loaded, so leaving them on the seat was just the most convenient option in the moment. When he does wind up back here we see him examining the bullets and he immediately gets suspicious and starts going through his photos. He sees the one marked "Teddy" that says "Don't believe his lies. He is the one. Kill him." Teddy tries to talk him out of it but the scene ends with Leonard shooting Teddy.
Leonard is putting himself on Teddy's trail in his anger and confusion. Soon it won't be "his" problem anymore. In that moment he effectively lies to himself by wiping his hands of the act by leaving it up to fate to decide what happens to Teddy even though it's really Leonard's actions both in that moment and later that lead to Teddy's death. Since Leonard blames Teddy for manipulating him, he's now turning himself, Teddy's weapon, around and pointing it back at Teddy. Teddy will soon be hoisted with his own petard as they say i.e. there's a certain level of poetic justice to Teddy being punished in this way because he has been taking advantage of Leonard's condition to do his dirty work.
TLDR: Leonard unloads the gun because:

he wants to reduce the risk of him killing anyone immediately because he doesn't accept that he's a killer but he wants to ensure Teddy gets a taste of his own medicine — he's giving himself a new "puzzle to solve"
the bullets may act as a clue to arouse his suspicions later (though it's unclear if he really could have predicted that in the moment and maybe that's just a coincidence)

